Манглинг функций в LLVM
Пишу компилятор с бэкендом LLVM IR. Встал выбор в реализации методов класса. MyClass.Hello или манглинг по стандарту C++ ABI? Происходит ли манглинг имен функций с . в LLVM?
C++ с clang и LLVM API установить нет возможности, а знать надо прям сейчас.
